# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In my power shell script I am loading a custom assembly and then instantiating a class of that assembly by `New-Object`.

`Assembly.LoadFile()` executes successfully but `New-Object` statement gives the bellow exception.

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of i
ts dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("MyAssembly.dll")
$a=New-Object MyAssembly.MyClass -ArgumentList "arg1"
```

This custom assembly references only the following assemblies

```
System
System.Core
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.Xml.Linq
System.Data
System.Xml
```

I tried explicitly loading the System.Runtime.Serialization dll like below. But same exception

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
```

Any idea?

Comment: Q: Is your assembly registered in the gac?

Comment: No, it's not registered in GAC.

Comment: Try LoadFrom to see if it works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `LoadFile`. Since you are using Powershell V2, the preferred method is `Add-Type`

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "MyLibrary.dll"
```

http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/29/how-to-load-net-assemblies-in-a-powershell-session/ has a good list of the different ways available to import a library into the current shell runspace.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx is the technet documentaion on Add-Type and has examples including how to use static methods in a loaded library

Comment: I'll just throw this out here aswell: http://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/add-type-vs-reflectionassembly-in.html Add-Type is really picky about the assemblies

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue when I tried to invoke 32-bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll from 64-bit Windows Powershell ISE. Later I used the same code in Windows Powershell ISE (x86) and I was able to invoke Oracle.DataAccess.dll file. Cheers!